# Проблема с отображением текста в TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

У меня есть `TextView`. В него загружается текст. Проблема заключается в том, что когда я загружаю не простой текст, а текст с различными стилями, которые парсятся через `Html.fromHtml()`, у меня начинает обрезаться последняя строка. Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему?

---

Со стилями:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без стилей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: видимо это зависит от выбранного размера шрифта и прочих атрибутов форматирования текста. Просто размеры самого текста и расстояния между ними заданы таким образом, что часть строки не входит в экран.

Comment: @pavlofff, это я понимаю, но я не знаю как это исправить. Есть идеи?

Comment: Я несколько не понял, вы как хотите, чтобы вело себя приложение, если внизу остается места на пол строки +/-?

Comment: Заверните TextView в ScrollView.

Comment: У Html.fromHtml() есть ограничение на количество символов которое он может парсить, возможно проблема в этом

Comment: @pavlofff скорее не на экран, а в TextView, так как видно отступ. Просто эта вью рисует текст так как ей сказали, но обрезается размером канваса.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вставить это в компонент `scrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

По факту у вас страница не поместилась на экране. У вас есть 2 пути решения:

1. Вставить TextView в ScrollView и у вас страница будет скролиться, но я так понимаю, что у вас по страничное отображение без скрола;
2. Второй вариант, это разбивать текст так, чтобы он четко влезал на экран, тоесть вы берете текущий размер шрифта и расчитываете сколько строчек у вас влезет (учитывая форматирование глав и тд, у них же размеры отличаются). после того как расчитали можно и отбирать следующую порцию текста, которая 100% влезет на экран.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить `android:scrollbars="vertical"` для `TextView` в xml

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в `TextView`

```
android:layout_gravity="fill"
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать WebView и его метод loadDataWithBaseURL:

```
String str="<html><body>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.<ul><li>Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.</li></ul></body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, str, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```